# Android App error:

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner developer and I am making an app.
I get the error: **Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)**
This is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.goldennuggetnlapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void myClickHandler(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class));

     }
    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.view.View;

    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    import android.widget.Button;
```

I don't know how to fix it. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Try below code, remove your imports from onCreate and try, and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
package com.example.goldennuggetnlapp;

import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
    }

    public void myClickHandler(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class));

     }
    // more code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your class like this.

```
package com.example.goldennuggetnlapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
    }


    public void myClickHandler(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class));

     }
```

You have imported some of the portion inside Activity that is not acceptable.

Comment: @FD_, yup sorry, my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.goldennuggetnlapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
    }

    public void myClickHandler(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class));

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all import statements must be at the beginning of the file (right after the package declaration if there is one). So you'll have to move all your import statements to the top.